# id like command to See group information

Tags: linux

Before adding any group by using groupadd command. I want to see the group is exists or not. Thats why i want to know is there  any command like id command to see group information in Linux?

I am able to see the group information in /etc/group or giving command

```
 $ getent group groupname
```

But I am finding such easy command like id to see group exists or not.

Comment: Please note that Stackoverflow is for programming related questions only. Please review the [help/on-topic] for what topics can be asked here. This question may be appropriate on other SE sites such as [unix.se]. Check their help first to see if the question belongs there and if so you can click the "flag" link and select "in need of moderator attention" to request migration there.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: Just use `groupmod groupname >/dev/null 2>&1` and check the return value for `4`, `6` or `9` (group doesn't exist, or group already in use).